# Customizing YAxis in Oracle Apex Chart

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, apex-code, apexcharts

I have the following situation in Apex (v22.11): I have a chart with the type 'Combination'; so the series are one line chart and 4 bar charts. The format of the y axis is 'Percent' (so the numbers are <= 1). The line chart has a fixed value (85% or .85) and the bar charts have variable (percent) numbers.
I have the following problem: I can't customize the y axis of this chart and I can't explain why.

The best solution for me in this case is, when the chart show the fixed value on this y axis on one side and on the other side the y axis customize the steps automatically. Because I am a beginner in JavaScript I could not make it happen.

Because I am a beginner, I tried the following under Attributes -> Advanced -> JavaScript Initialization Code:

```
function(options){
   options.yAxis.step = .05;
   return options;
}
```

Among other things, it should display the number 85%, but he only displays the numbers 0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, and so on. When I change the step to '= .5' (for example) then it works and Apex customize it. And I don't know why?? I searched on the attributes of oj-chart but I don't find another possiblities to change the Y Axis.

This point is also important:
On this line chart (Series) I can not activate the label 'Show' because my SQL Query is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLASSROOM,
--Calculation for Bar1
--Calculation for Bar2
--Calculation for Bar3
--Calculation for Bar4
.85 AS Target
FROM EMP_SAMPLE
GROUP BY (CLASSROOM)
```

And when I activate this, the percent number of this line will be shown three or four times on the chart depending on how much classroom (for the x axis) you have in the database. And I need the value only one time for this line.

Of course another solution could be the following: I write the percent number on or left-side or right-side or under this line with JavaScript (but of course only one time), but here I have the same problem as a beginner and I don't know how. (Or is it possible to customize it with HTML and CSS?)

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.